# Using Field on an Object of unknown type

Tags: java, reflection

My application builds a cache of `Field`'s that will be accessed later on during its lifetime. I figured creating an index of `Field`'s would be quicker then doing a lookup every time I need to access the `Field`. Though, I am not seeing anyway to use the `Field` on a Java object.

POJO:

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Field> fields = new HashMap<>();

    for (Field field : Employee.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fields.add(field.getName(), field);
    }

    Object employee = new Employee("bob", "saget");

    fields.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
        // Showing intent, obviously getFieldValue doesn't exist
        System.out.println("Field " + entry.getKey() + ": " + employee.getClass().getFieldValue(entry.getValue());
    });
}
```

Expected output:

```
Field firstName: bob
Field lastName: saget
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-

Comment: You most probably shouldn't use reflection, though. If you explained what you're actually trying to achieve, we would probably be able to provide a cleaner, safer, faster strategy.

Comment: @JBNizet I have created a set of custom annotations that expose POJO's to my framework. The user provides a package to scan these POJO's and are indexed by the framework. Until that point, the framework has no concept of these classes. The annotations instruct my framework to accomplish certain tasks. I know this incredibly vague and probably doesn't help but I'm pretty sure reflection is the only way for my framework to understand the structure of these POJO's.

Comment: And thank you. This is my first go at using `Field` concept from the reflection package. It worked!

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific problem is.